# How I get the html dom before it's rendered in ios webview

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I would like to check the error code inside a tag of webview, but I want to close the app as soon as I get error code (eg: database error). So I dont want the whole webview to show up, just close my ios app if I find error code in tags of webview DOM.

So how can I get the HTML tags before it's rendered in ios webview?
Is there anything like webview proxy or response intercept?

Comment: " just close my ios app if I find error code in tags of webview DOM" that sounds like a terrible user experience.

Comment: you can try using HTML parsers like `SwiftSoup` or `Kanna`.

Comment: For example user click log out, and the webview return error code like "loggedout:true"